# XSLT HMAC-SHA1 - OAuth Authentication

Tags: xml, xslt, oauth

I've been trying to create a Signature for OAuth Authentication for an external REST API call  however I can't seem to find a XSLT function which can execute within Eclipse.

Here some sample code:

```
<Signature>
  <xsl:value-of select="dp:hmac( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1',$password,$BaseString)"/>
</Signature>
```

I've tried to use the following namespace in my XSLT but it doesn't seem to work. I  keep getting the error: ***1 error detected.
Cannot find a matching 3-argument function named {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1}***

Wondering if anyone has ever executed HMAC-SHA1 hashing algorithm within XSLT?

BTW - I am using Saxon EE 9.4.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

The URL "http://www.w3.org..." seems out of place in **select=**

Typically I only see URLs like that in the **xmlns** namespace declarations.

This is just my thought on the topic, I have not executed HMAC-SHA1 within XSLT myself.